# jdbcTemplate - Convert data from JSON column

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Tools: Spring Booot v2.1.3.RELEASE, MySQL 5.7

I have table with column of type JSON named "properties".
I use jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql) method to read from this table.
Rest service returns something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "users",
    "properties": "{\"prop1\": \"value1\"}",
    "description": "smpl descr1",
    "log_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "members",
    "properties": null,
    "description": "sample description 2",
    "log_enabled": true
  }
]
```

As you can see the "properties" object is type of String.
How to force jdbcTemplete to convert data from JSON column into JSON instead of String?

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "users",
    "properties": {
      "prop1": "value1"
    },
    "description": "smpl descr1",
    "log_enabled": false
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "members",
    "properties": null,
    "description": "sample description 2",
    "log_enabled": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sorry that `JdbcTemplete` does not have such function. You have to convert the JSON string to the java object by yourself using your favourite JSON library.

For example , in case of `Jackson` , you can convert any JSON string to a Map using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = "{\"prop1\": \"value1\" , \"prop2\": 123}";

Map<String,Object> result = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>() {});

result.get("prop1") // "value1"
result.get("prop2") // 123
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you Ken.

Comment: Glad to hear. If you think my answer is useful , please consider to upvote and accept my answer :P